# Is it possible to see a sequence in all_sequences without having the SELECT right on the sequence?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I need to retrieve the list of available sequences of a certain database schema in an Oracle 10g database (10.2.0.3).

With the schema owner, I can simply do something like the following to achieve this:

```
SELECT sequence_name FROM all_sequences WHERE sequence_owner = 'ABCDEF';
```

However, If I use a user which has a custom "read-only" role assigned, that user does not get any rows when executing that query.
I've played around a bit and found out that granting the `SELECT` option on the sequences to the read-only role makes those sequences appear in the `all_sequences` view when connected with the read-only user.

However this means that the read-only user is able to do

```
SELECT my_sequence.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL;
```

which is a no-go for our situation (after all, the read-only user shall not be able to modify anything, not even sequences).

Is there another way for retrieving the sequences which does not allow selecting `NEXTVAL`?

---

[Edit:]

If I do

```
SELECT DISTINCT sequence_owner FROM all_sequences;
```

I get the following list:

```
SEQUENCE_OWNER                 
------------------------------ 
MDSYS                          
DMSYS                          
OLAPSYS                        
XDB                            
SYS                            

5 rows selected
```

After using the `system` user to do

```
GRANT SELECT ANY DICTIONARY TO MY_USER;
```

the result stays the same (revoke does not change anything either).
Granting the `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` instead does not work either.

Granting `SELECT` on at least one of the sequences however changes the result to include my own schema owner.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to grant SELECT ANY DICTIONARY privilege, but it's very bad for the security reasons, so, I guess, your DBA will deny it.

Good decision is to create [table function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm) publishes required data. By default this function will work with AUTHID DEFINER rights, so you should just grant it to read-only user and it would receive sequences info without any chance to change them.

Comment: We could in fact utilize the `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` priviledge despite the security issues (which are not that much of a concern for our case). Unfortunately, that priviledge does not provide the expected result (see my edited question), at least not in Oracle 10g. I'm gonna give the table function approach a try now.

Comment: after giving the SELECT ANY DICTIONARY priviledge you need to select from DBA_SEQUENCES instead of all_sequences

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I can come up with is to grant the user `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY`. This will give them access to `DBA_SEQUENCES` (as well as all of the other `DBA_` views) without needing permissions on the objects.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` does not seem to work, at least for Oracle 10g. See my edited question for details.

Comment: It's important to note  that `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` will not change the behavior of the `ALL_SEQUENCES` view, but, instead, grants access to the `DBA_SEQUENCES` view.